# Seventy minus one

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning

I was watching a series and came across a dialogue which was, “I would love to “af you see kay” you in 70 minus 1”.
What does 70 minus 1 mean here? Is  it an idiom?

Comment: What series, and is this your transcription, or a transcription off the internet, or off the subtitles or what.  Please be specific about the source.

Answer (score 1):

What does "af you see kay" spell out?

How much is 70 minus 1?
[American Heritage Dictionary "sixty-nine"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sixty-nine)

Comment: Do people actually say *f\*\*\* you in sixty-nine*? I mean, isn't the verb more often used to suggest penetrative sex rather than oral stuff? I suppose in general people might mean a lot of things by it, but when used in conjunction with the actual *position* which doesn't really suggest that (again, in general), wouldn't something else be more appropriate? https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sixtynine suggests *do*, *have*, and *be in* + position. Maybe the speaker is imparting a different flavor to the meaning by using that specific verb, in which they're a bit more "active"?

Comment: I think f*** has a broader interpretation too. It's defined as "sexual intercourse", and I think 69 falls into that category, unless you're Bill Clinton.